# Meaning of "such" in 'such is the son' (Homer's Odyssey)

Tags: grammar, inversion

[Source:](http://swcta.net/moore/files/2014/08/The-Odyssey-Greek-Translation.pdf) Book 1, Lines 258-260, *The Odyssey*, by Homer, translated by Robert Fitzgerald,

> The gods decreed
>   no lack of honor in this generation:
>   such is the son Penélopê bore in you.

Does this mean the following:

> The son is an example that shows that the Gods decreed no lack of honor?

Is this "such" the same as "I don't know such."?

Answer (score 4):

"such is the son" means "that is what the son is like".

So

> The gods decreed no lack of honor in this generation: such is the son Penélopê bore in you.

means

- The gods decreed no lack of honor in this generation
- The son Penélopê bore in you (who, we assume, is of this generation) has no lack of honour

Comment: So this is an inversion sentence?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: Or to be more precise, the clause after the colon is inverted. The clause before it is normal.

Answer (score 1):

"such is the son" : just like the son