# Wrong verb in "the son ... is no lack of honor ..."?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

[Source:](http://swcta.net/moore/files/2014/08/The-Odyssey-Greek-Translation.pdf) Book 1, Lines 257-260, *The Odyssey*, by Homer, translated by Robert Fitzgerald

> Then grey-eyed Athena said:
>   “The gods decreed *no lack of honor in this generation*:
>   **such is** the son Penélopê bore in you.

As per [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16343/8712), **such** here functions as a pronoun denoting the italicised. To illustrate my issue, I rewrite the main clause after the colon, firstly by reordering it into SVO sentence structure:

1. =  the son Penélopê bore in you **is such**.

2. = the son Penélopê bore in you **is *no lack of honor in this generation***.

3. the son Penélopê bore in you **HAS *no lack of honor in this generation***

Yet 2 is wrong, because 'to be' cannot be followed by a noun phrase. So should the bolded instead be **'such HAS'**, which when rearranged into SVO, matches with 3?

Comment: Such = of that ilk

Answer (score 2):

> The gods decreed no lack of honor in this generation: such is the son Penélopê bore in you.

Why do you think **such** should be literally transplanted with the piece of text it refers back to?

> The son Penelope bore in you is such that he has no lack of honor, just as the gods decreed any person born in this generation would be.

or

> The son Penelope has in your person is brave. This fits perfectly with the gods' decree that any person born in this generation would be brave.

or

> Well, I see Penelope has a brave man for a son! Just like the gods' decreed for this generation.

*Such* could be roughly interpreted as *not lacking honor*, or simply speaking *brave*.